# How do I send csrftoken from Django Rest Framework backend to React Native front-end?

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am building an application after finishing up my website. Now, the backend for both of these should be common, but Django's csrf token is meant to be a security against this. Since I am not using a web browser, I am unable to get a csrf token cookie. At the same time, django will need it to access its APIs.

Is there any way I can get the cookie from Django and get it into React Native?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you want to do. But if you are writing a native application, why don't you use a token identification mechanism?

There are lots of simple (and less simple solutions out there).

Assuming you are using django rest framework.

- Simple built-in Token authentication
  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication
- Token, but with expiry and DB encryption
  https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox
- JWT
  https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Comment: I'm already using one of these! However, at the same time, Django uses an inbuilt CSRF security mechanism which tries to ensure that the requests to the server come in through a browser, hence protecting it against disruptive headless attacks. As useful as this security is, but the React native environment does not run a web browser, and hence, Django assumes they are corrupt requests. That's the issue I am facing. I need to be able to tell django that these requests are perfectly safe and it should let them pass without the CSRF. At the same time, I do want the security to be present for web.

Comment: What authentication backend are you using? A combination of `SessionAuthentication` and `TokenAuthentication`? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am using `JWTAuthentication` from rest_framework.

Comment: I thought you might be interested in https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/pull/157 . This is the right way to do it for the web. The token would in both the response body for mobile and in a http only cookie for web. CSRF token is generated and enabled for unsafe requests.

Answer (score 0):

May I know your login URL?  Use rest-auth login URL. Allauth URL gives Csrf issue.